# Add new column based on odd/even condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have the `dataframe` below:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
my_df
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

I want to add a column `B` with values `X` if the corresponding number in `A` is odd, otherwise `Y`. I would like to do it in this way if possible:

```
my_df['B'] = np.where(my_df['A'] IS ODD, 'X', 'Y')
```

I don't know how to check if the value is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were so close!

```
my_df['b'] = np.where(my_df['A'] % 2 != 0, 'X', 'Y')
```

`value % 2 != 0` will check if a number is odd. Where are `value % 2 == 0` will check for evens.

Output:

```
   A  b
0  1  X
1  2  Y
2  3  X
```